# How do I calculate quadratic weighted Kappa in a Tidymodels pipeline?

Tags: r, tidymodels

I have the following code as a simple example.

```
library(tidymodels)
library(bonsai)

train_folds <- vfold_cv(data = train, strata = target)

train_rec <- recipe(formula = target ~ ., data = train) %>% 
  update_role(Id, new_role = "ID")

gb_mod <- boost_tree(engine = "lightgbm", 
                     mtry = 11, 
                     mode = "classification",
                     trees = 100)

gb_workflow <- workflow(preprocessor = train_rec, 
                        spec = gb_mod)

model_fit <- gb_workflow %>% fit_resamples(train_folds,
                                           metrics = metric_set(kap, roc_auc, accuracy))

model_fit %>% collect_metrics()
```

The `kap` function calculates the Kappa metric which has no weighting by default. To calculate quadratic weighted Kappa you must add `weighting = "quadratic"` as a parameter, which `metric_set()` doesn't seem to accept. How can I include QWK in the metrics output?

Apologies if this has been answered already but I couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make an alternate function (just by wrapping the original):

```r
library(yardstick)
#> For binary classification, the first factor level is assumed to be the event.
#> Use the argument `event_level = "second"` to alter this as needed.
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

data(hpc_cv, package = "modeldata")

# See example in ?metric_set examples
kap_quad <- function(data, truth, estimate, na_rm = TRUE, ...) {
  kap(
    data = data,
    truth = !! rlang::enquo(truth),
    estimate = !! rlang::enquo(estimate),
    # set weighting = "quadratic"
    weighting = "quadratic",
    na_rm = na_rm,
    ...
  )
}
kap_quad <- new_numeric_metric(kap_quad, "maximize")



met <- metric_set(kap_quad)
hpc_cv %>% 
  met(obs, estimate = pred)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 kap     multiclass     0.692

# no weighting
hpc_cv %>% 
  kap(obs, estimate = pred)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 kap     multiclass     0.508
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This worked. The only problem is that it still comes up in the `collect_metrics()` output as `kap`, so for example, you can't directly compare linear and quadratic weighting without refitting the model. It's not an issue in this instance, but I wonder is there a way to change the display name.